# Magento Categories

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I have A magento Store, But Last Week My Stupid Brother Delete all the files from server just to apply a new theme. Now The problem is that all my categories and Products are lost. BUT I HAVE THE ORIGIONAL DATABASE or That Store. Now anyone can guide me to proceedure from where i can export old categories from SQL Database and Import it To The New DB. It Would Save me Weeks of Hard Work. please anyone guide me.

Comment: Why not just use the original database? Magento themes are independent of the database.

Comment: Cant Do That, my New store is configured on new database and already 500+ products have been added

Comment: What about your orders? It would make more sense to export your 500+ products from the new database, then revert back to old database, and import the products that you exported. - seems like way less hassle, and export/import of the products can be handled via core dataflow.

Answer (score 0):

Just upload the same version of magento you were using and point it to the same database. You will need to add your images again but everything else will be in place.